# how can I create circular pictures in Unity3d taken by an user that are double sided?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on balls with discs inside made from pictures taken by the user then made circular and double sided so you can see the same image on both sides of the disc. I use a sprite mask to make the pictures circular. After I instantiate the prefab and then change the sprites of 2 of the children, which are the discs we want to change. The discs are now invisible, how do I get them to appear?

```
GameObject ch = Instantiate(character, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);

GameObject ChildGameObject1 = ch.transform.GetChild (1).gameObject;
GameObject ChildGameObject2 = ch.transform.GetChild (2).gameObject;

ChildGameObject1.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = GetComponent<ChangeSprite>().getSprite();
ChildGameObject2.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = GetComponent<ChangeSprite>().getSprite();
```

edit: I fixed it, I don't know how but I fixed it.

Comment: what does the function .getSprite() do? Can you send the code? Chances are that's returning null or the wrong sprite.

Comment: getSprite() returns a sprite in a class that uses DontDestroyOnLoad to preserve a sprite between scenes. I had problems changing sprites before I started using the ChangeSprite component and it works on its' own so I don't think it has anything to do with that.

Comment: It's not a problem with getting the sprite itself then it might be a simpler problem like the transform position being weird or the sprite renderer/gameobject being disabled. It doesn't look like the code itself would cause any problems thought except maybe using GetChild(1) for ChildGameObject1 (which would actually get the second child, unless that's intentional)

Comment: GetChild was for the second and third child, the first is the ball outside the disc.